# Check file existence and grep in the same if statement

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to append a string into a file if the file exists and if it is not already in it. Otherwise, create the file with the string in it.

```
if [ -f PATH_TO_FILE ]; then
  if ! grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE; then
    echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
  fi
else
  echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
fi
```

I want to optimize that with AND/OR conditions in the if statements but struggle with the syntax.

I tried to do the following but it does not work if the file does not exist.

```
grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE || echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

Can anyone help me finding the sweetest syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
if [[ ! -f PATH_TO_FILE ]] || ! grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE; then
   echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

This

```
grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE || echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

does the equivalent functionality as the `if ..else` statements.

So, if you don't like to see the error message when the file doesn't exist, you could redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

```
grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE 2>/dev/null || echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this too:

```
[ ! -f PATH_TO_FILE ] || ! grep -q PATTERN PATH_TO_FILE && echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

> Explanation:

At first it checks for existing file. If it doesn't exist, the first condition is `true` and thus the miidle part (`grep`) is skipped and `echo` part is executed, i.e file is created with STRING in it.
And if the file exist, the first condition is false, thus second condition is executed, and the `echo` part executes only if the `grep` part is `true`. Thus if the `PATTERN` matches, the `echo` part won't be executed i.e `STRING` won't be written in the file if PATTERN matches.

> Example:

```
[ ! -f PATH_TO_FILE ] || ! grep -q STRING PATH_TO_FILE && echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
[ ! -f PATH_TO_FILE ] || ! grep -q STRING PATH_TO_FILE && echo STRING >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

This will create a file named PATH_TO_FILE and write STRING in it. Even though the same code is executed two times, it won't write STRING twice. Because at second time, STRING is found in PATH_TO_FILE.

And if you execute it with a second STRING and PATTERN it will write to it:

```
[ ! -f PATH_TO_FILE ] || ! grep -q STRING2 PATH_TO_FILE && echo STRING2 >> PATH_TO_FILE
```

STRING2 will be appended to the file.

Comment: That won't create the file if it is nonexistent.

Comment: Now if the file exists but doesn't have that text it won't do it... :-)

Comment: Again, it won't create the file if it is nonexistent. Your 4 test cases are the 4 permutations of file exists/doesn't exist and string is/is not found.

Comment: It seems I had a quite hard time understanding what the OP wants. I have edited it again, and with some explanation.

Comment: Bingo. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74312/discussion-between-jahid-and-peter-bowers).